# Two query in one with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, recursion

This is what I'm trying to do something similar to the following request, but I don't know if it's possible with the SQL-Server syntax:

```
declare @idClient int

select @idClient=idClient from table
where entite is null and (SELECT * from table where entite=@idClient) is null
```

Thanks.

Comment: I can't make much sense of that. In what way would that be recursive? What is it that you are trying to do? Perhaps you should describe what it is that you want to accomplish, instead of asking about how to do it the way that you think that it should be done.

Comment: What is the relationship between TableH and TableC?

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake It's was the same table.

Comment: No idea what you actually want, but that is a very bad way to set a value for a variable. If you do that in a selct, the query must have one and one one result which seems unlikely when searching for where entite is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
SELECT t1.[idClient]
FROM   [table] t1
WHERE  [entite] IS NULL 
       AND NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT NULL
           FROM   [table] t2
           WHERE  t2.[entite]=t1.[idClient]
       )
```